# Help me find a material with low acoustic impedance but high wave velocity

Tags: materials, plastic, acoustics

I'm trying to find a material that would have two seemingly opposite qualities. I need something with low acoustic impedance, like a plastic, but also with high wave velocity like a metal.
Here are the exact requirements:

- shear wave velocity > 2500 m/s
- acoustic impedance < 8 MRayl

Is there material you know of that would be a good in between? Glassy carbon is a good candidate for example.

edit:

Some more thoughts, if we assume that:

`acoustic impedance = density x longitudinal wave velocity`

and assume a ratio between shear and longitudinal wave velocity of at best 1.5 (this is the lowest I found while doing my research)

For a maximum impedance of 8e6 Rayl, and a shear wave velocity of 2500 m.s^-1 minimum,

$density < 8*10^6 /\ (2500 * 1.5)$

$density < 2133\ kg.m^3$

So the density of the materila I'm looking for must not excede a density of **2133 kg.m3** while having a high sound velocity.

Comment: the term is `shear`

Comment: Beryllium copper has unusually low acoustic impedance  but I do not know the numbers.

Comment: Also, the unit for acoustic impedance is [Rayl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayl), not Ray.

Comment: Try sodium chloride i.e. salt crystal. When applying material density and elastic bulk modulus taken from Wikipedia, the characteristic impedance is about 7,3MRayl and the velocity is 3350m/s. I'm afraid the material is not generally available as big and solid enough crystals. But a patient person may grow one by himself. Some practical troubles may  occur in high humidity environments.

Comment: You might consider impedance matching by putting a quarter-wave layer (or multilayer) of a "plastic" on the input face of your metal body.   This is how "AR" (antireflective) coatings are used in the optical regime

Comment: @blacksmith37 unfortunately the impedance is still to high.

Comment: @user287001 The numbers are close, thanks. Unfortunately it also needs to be rated for high temperatures.